# Need to add landing to _blank on Javascript code for random image/link load script

Tags: javascript

I have an ad rotator script I got here, but it doesn't have a line for making the links go on a blank page vs parent. Or anywhere where it shows the specifics.

```
function randomzero (n)
{
 return ( Math.floor ( Math.random ( )*0.9999999999999999* (n + 1)) );}

//IV. assign any random number from 0 to 2 to x.

x = randomzero(4);


//V. display the image
document.write('<a href="http://' + randomlink[x] + '">');
document.write('<img alt="random ad banner"src="' + randompic[x] +   '"/>');
document.write('</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it does. Add a `target` to the link it creates:

```
document.write('<a target="_blank" href="http://' + randomlink[x] + '">');
```